# AWS Cloudfront behaviors not routing to the correct path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two s3 buckets, *images* and *website*.

I set up cloudfront to have two origins for these buckets.

The default behavior routes to *website*, which is the build folder of a hello world react app.

The behavior for the *images* bucket is */images/*.  I uploaded an image, test.png in the images bucket.

For some reason, every route in /images/, takes me back to the website bucket (I know this because a 404 on the bucket routes back to index.html).  This means it doesn't even look at the image bucket.  I have no clue why it never hits the images bucket.

Could it be because I'm using error handling on it?.

Here's the CDK code to make the cloudfront.

```
const websiteDistribution = new Distribution(this, 'WebsiteDistribution', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    origin: new S3Origin(this._websiteBucket, {
      originAccessIdentity: oaiWeb,
      originPath: '/website-ui',
    }),
    allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
    compress: true,
    viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
  },
  additionalBehaviors: {
    'images/*': {
      origin: new S3Origin(this._imagesBucket, {
        originAccessIdentity: oaiWeb,
      }),
      allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
      compress: true,
      viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY
    },
  },
  defaultRootObject: 'index.html',
  domainNames: [`www.${props.domain}`],
  enabled: true,
  priceClass: PriceClass.PRICE_CLASS_100,
  certificate: this._websiteCert,
  logBucket: this._logBucket,
  httpVersion: HttpVersion.HTTP2,
  logFilePrefix: 'logs',
  enableLogging: true,
  errorResponses: [
    {
      httpStatus: 403,
      responseHttpStatus: 200,
      responsePagePath: '/index.html',
      ttl: Duration.seconds(0),
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the full path route was forwarding to the images bucket.
test.png in the main s3 directory wasn't found.  It needed to be in an *images* folder in the *images* bucket.

Example:

1. URL PATH = **cloudfront**/images/test.png
2. Route to behavior */images*
3. In *images* bucket, look for file */images/test.png*
4. File was not found since test.png is NOT in subdirectory *images*.
5. Cloudfront now looks at the default behavior (*)
6. The file does not exist in the website bucket, throw 404 error

I added a folder *images* in the *images* bucket and it found the file.